# How to remove sound from sound spectrum in animation nodes?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes, audio

this is infuriating. Even if I delete the sound spectrum node, even if I restart Blender, the sounds that I loaded into sound spectrum node will remain there to be played simultaneously. How do I clear that node from previously loaded sounds?

Answer (score 2):

When you load sound file in sound spectrum it will automatically appear on video sequencer.
You can remove audio from there.

Comment: Wow Hari, I kept looking everywhere else. Thanks mate, thanks a lot!